# AWS autoscaling upgrade on EB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

So if I want to change my autoscaling instances and upgrade them,
as soon as I do apply the changes and it creates the instance it fails after 5 min

because of (Target.ResponseCodeMismatch)

and it keeps on being replaced

how to overcome the issue here ??

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you tested your upgraded instances? Do they still work the same way the old ones did? The error is indicating the health checks are now failing

Comment: Yes now it works but only because I've move the range of health check response code in the range of 200-499 but before and I guess the legit way should only be when 200, at least that was the default one which made it fail

Comment: The health check happens directly on the instance so you can check what actual response you get if you log on to the instance and run `wget http://localhost/(health check path)` and see what response type you get

Comment: ok thank you so much, will try to debug that way

Comment: So if I put the health check to 404 and the path to " / " the health check passes as a healthy. What does that mean ?

Comment: what I get ``` HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 20 Jul 2023 11:47:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 5832
Connection: keep-alive
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

Comment: If you configured nginx to serve your site on by its server name then. It's probably fine that requesting another host that nginx isn't configured to serve will show 404 (it probably tries to show the default website and that has been misconfigured somehow).

Comment: Ok I see, any tips on how could I overcome this. As tbh I did several times the upgrade of the instance type in autoscaling config on EB and this never happened but suddenly now I get this issue. No super experienced with devOps here

Comment: I don't know if there would be a reason for this to happen just from upgrading instance types. It is possible at some point the instance type required a different underlying set of software with different defaults e.g. a newer nginx version or something like that . Might be worth comparing the default nginx configurations between old and new to compare if anything changed

Comment: OK so I've solved by creating custom heath check api call that returns 200 which it means the ec2 is healthy and now it's all fine. Thank you again for you replies I appreciated it